# Insert SQL statement on access which would let me extract data according to data from another table?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, foreign-key-relationship, sql-insert

So far I've managed to extract data from one table to another.

```
 INSERT INTO Town ( Town_name)
 SELECT DISTINCT Locality
 FROM Students_Record
 WHERE Locality <> NULL ;
```

What I Tried to do but there was an error as the locality was not found or tried different methods with sub queries but they dont seem to return anything.

what I've thought it would be like

First extracted all the town_names with the previous query, then...

```
            INSERT INTO Town(Country)
            SELECT ID FROM Country
            WHERE Town_name = (SELECT locality FROM Students_record) AND
            Country_name = (SELECT country FROM Students_record)
```

The Town table is connected via country with the country ID (Country) to country (Town). The only difficulty that I'm facing is that ;

I Cannot automatically insert all the towns along with the country FK (The countries were extracted from the Students_records with a simple sql statement using the DISTINCT). As the town names are being extracted from the table Students_Record which is a denormalized table in which I'm trying to fix.

So the question is... How will I indicate the Country ID in the insert statement to correspond with the DISTINCT locality (Student_records) to match the Country in the Student_records.

Tables Summary

COUNTRY 
id PK Auto number,
country_name

TOWN 
id PK, 
town_name,
country FK,

Students_records 
id,
town,
country ,
etc....

Re-cap : Country names where extracted from Students_Records.Country (From all the table using the DISTINCT Keyword)

Town names were also extracted from this table using a similar method.

Town.Country ID must correspond to the same  Country name that had the town_name in the same row.

Comment: `locality <> null` is impossible. sql null is "poisonous". it is IMPOSSIBLE for `null` to be equal to anything, also also impossible for null to be UNEQUAL to anything. and this applies to itself. you can NOT test for nullity with (in)equality tests. that's why there's `foo is null` and `foo is not null`.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question

Comment: which is why that was a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: Sorry mate I've been working on this for a while now ... it's getting on my nerves , I used the Is not null in the first statement as there were some null values in the Students_records so I've eliminated those by putting the != null in the where clause.... That's how I've extracted the town_names from various town entries found in the Students_record

Comment: and I'm telling you, you can't test for null values with `=`, or `!=`. any operation involving null produces null as a result. `null = null` will ALSO produce null, never true/false.

Comment: Ohh.. flashbulb : ) It is there for no reason then removed that where clause ran the same query got the same results, so yes it is unnecessary a very good point there sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Use "is not null" instead of " <> null"